# DataTable Range Datetime Filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, filter, datatable

I've a datatable which i fill with ajax response. In the response i'm getting a string date data. I can write that data on datatable but i can't filter the data with date range. I've try so much way but i can't solve this. some of my trying i get " fnDraw()" is not function or some error like this. how can I make the range filter ?

JavaScrıpt code :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  var table = $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/History/GetCallbackHistory',
        data: { UserId: document.getElementById("callbackuserid").value },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (obj, textstatus) {
            $('#callback_table').DataTable({
                "pagingType": "input",
                "language":
                {
                    "processing": "<div class='loader'>Loading...</div>",
                    "paginate": {
                        "previous": "",
                        "next": ""
                    },
                },
                dom: "<'row'<'container-c'pi<'permuheader'<'refresh-button'>><'tlength'l>>>"
                    + "<'row'>"
                    + "<'row'<'col-sm-12't>r>",
                data: obj,
                columns: [
                    {
                        "data": "Id"
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "DateCallback"
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "callbackId"
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "Task_name"
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "callbackStatus"
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "Point"
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "TransactionType"
                    },
                    {
                        "data": "DateEnd"
                    }
                ]
            });
        },
        error: function (obj, textstatus) {
            alert(obj.msg);
        }
    });
    $("#datepicker_from").datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImageOnly: false,
        "onSelect": function (date) {
            minDateFilter = new Date(date).getTime();
            table.fnDraw();
        }
    }).keyup(function () {
        minDateFilter = new Date(this.value).getTime();
        table.fnDraw();
    });

    $("#datepicker_to").datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImageOnly: false,
        "onSelect": function (date) {
            maxDateFilter = new Date(date).getTime();
            table.fnDraw();
        }
    }).keyup(function () {
        maxDateFilter = new Date(this.value).getTime();
        table.fnDraw();
    });
});

$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
    function (oSettings, aData, iDataIndex) {
        if (typeof aData._date == 'undefined') {
            aData._date = new Date(aData[1]).getTime();
        }

        if (minDateFilter && !isNaN(minDateFilter)) {
            if (aData._date < minDateFilter) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        if (maxDateFilter && !isNaN(maxDateFilter)) {
            if (aData._date > maxDateFilter) {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use jQuery's `ajax` like this:

```
var table = $.ajax({ ... });
```

You are assigning the jQuery object to your `table` variable. You are *not* assigning the DataTable from the `success` function to the `table` variable.

This is why, when you try to use `table.fnDraw()`, you get that specific error: Your `table` is not a DataTable. The ajax call is *asynchronous* - it does not return anything from the `success` call in the normal flow of your code.

Instead, the simplest alternative that I would recommend is to re-arrange your code to use DataTables' built-in support for `ajax`.

In this new approach we do not need to use the jQuery `ajax` function at all - so we completely remove that from the code. Instead, we do this:

```js
var table = $('#callback_table').DataTable({
  "ajax": {
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "/History/GetCallbackHistory",
    "data": {
      UserId: document.getElementById("callbackuserid").value
    },
    "dataType": "json",
    "dataSrc": ""
  },
  "pagingType": "input",
  "language": {
    "processing": "<div class='loader'>Loading...</div>",
    "paginate": {
      "previous": "",
      "next": ""
    },
  },
  "dom": "<'row'<'container-c'pi<'permuheader'<'refresh-button'>><'tlength'l>>>" +
    "<'row'>" +
    "<'row'<'col-sm-12't>r>",
  "columns": [{
      "data": "Id"
    },
    {
      "data": "DateCallback"
    },
    {
      "data": "callbackId"
    },
    {
      "data": "Task_name"
    },
    {
      "data": "callbackStatus"
    },
    {
      "data": "Point"
    },
    {
      "data": "TransactionType"
    },
    {
      "data": "DateEnd"
    }
  ]
});
```

The main point to note is the `ajax` section:

```
  "ajax": {
    "method": "GET",
    "url": "/History/GetCallbackHistory",
    "data": {
      UserId: document.getElementById("callbackuserid").value
    },
    "dataType": "json",
    "dataSrc": ""
  },
```

This is a wrapper around the jQuery `ajax` function. But it also uses a DataTables extension to jQuery's `ajax`: the `dataSrc` option. This option replaces your old `data: obj` option. It tells DataTables that your JSON response is a plain array.

Once you have done this, then your `table` variable will contain a valid DataTables object - and you can now use `table.fnDraw();`. But it would be better to use the modern name for this function: `table.draw();`.

If you have filtering problems, after that, you can refer to the official date range filtering example [DataTables date range filter](https://datatables.net/extensions/datetime/examples/integration/datatables), to make sure your approach matches the example's approach (but using your preferred `datepicker` controls).